# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.EmbeddedValueResolver

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am getting this error while running my spring boot application. I am trying to run the void main. I have copied my pom.xml as well. I guess something is wrong with my pom.xml but I can't figure out what. can someone please help me
to solve this issue.

Error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/EmbeddedValueResolver
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.<init>(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:72) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:633) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:517) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.bfm.app.cmpl.eventRecorder.Main.main(Main.java:22) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.EmbeddedValueResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>            
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Do you use embedded tomcat or Spring Boot without the web server? I mean, why do you have `<scope>provided</scope>` and also i don't think you need anything except `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-actuator`, because everything else is [Compile Dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.4.3.RELEASE) of `spring-boot-starter-web`

Comment: Thanks @varren! yes I removed the spring-boot-starter-tomcat and it works. I also changed the spring boot version to 1.4.1 and spring framework version to 4.3.5